# Kubernetes/Rancher Desktop "certificate signed by unknown authority" macOS

Tags: kubernetes, rancher, rancher-desktop

After installing Rancher Desktop on macOS 13.2.1 (Apple M1) I walk through the [Hello World](https://docs.rancherdesktop.io/how-to-guides/hello-world-example) documentation. During the "Deploy to Kubernetes" part I run into this problem:

```bash
$ kubectl run hello-world --image=nginx-helloworld:latest --image-pull-policy=Never --port=80 
I0306 08:42:03.954011    9988 versioner.go:58] Get "https://127.0.0.1:6443/version?timeout=5s": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
E0306 08:42:04.038118    9988 memcache.go:238] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "https://127.0.0.1:6443/api?timeout=32s": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
Unable to connect to the server: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

I kind of understand the error but I don't know how to fix it properly. I followed all the steps in the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you are getting is "Unable to connect to the server: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority".

As per this [document](https://ranchermanager.docs.rancher.com/v2.5/getting-started/installation-and-upgrade/resources/custom-ca-root-certificates)

> Services that Rancher needs to access are sometimes configured with a
> certificate from a custom/internal CA root, also known as self signed
> certificate. If the presented certificate from the service cannot be
> validated by Rancher, the following error displays: `x509: certificate signed by unknown authority.`
>
> To validate the certificate, the CA root certificates need to be added
> to Rancher. As Rancher is written in Go, we can use the environment
> variable `SSL_CERT_DIR` to point to the directory where the CA root
> certificates are located in the container. The CA root certificates
> directory can be mounted using the Docker volume option (`-v host-source-directory:container-destination-directory`) when starting
> the Rancher container.

Refer to this official [document](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/troubleshooting-kubeadm/#tls-certificate-errors)  for more information.